# How to combine the values of 2 html.textbox in razor mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two textbox;

```
<div class="col-xs-6">@Html.TextBox("SearchString")</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">@Html.TextBox("SearchString")</div>
```

How to combine the two textbox value before passing to the controller?

Hope my explanation is clear.

Thank you.

Comment: use a hidden set value there before posting to controller via jquery

Comment: you can combine both textboxes values at controller, why you want to combine at view ?

Comment: Thank you for the idea @SunilKumar. It works. Sorry I'm new to MVC.